# Get reference to matrix stored in an open window OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

After having called `cv::namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)` and `cv::imshow("window", mat)`, is it possible to regain a reference to `mat` - from outside its scope, only given the window name?

I see there are options to get properties of an open window but not its data.
The use case is I want to manipulate data of other windows in the mouseEvent callback function of one window. I know I could also provide the required mat object references for this use case.

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: probably not. It's easier to just have the matrix as a global

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk can I access the matrix shown in an open window? sth like `cv::Mat mat; cv::matFromWindow("window", mat);`, which pastes the matrix displayed currently in the window into `mat`.

Comment: Not what you were asking for, but in my code I have a c++ class which encapsulates an OpenCV window and its “backing store” as a `cv::Mat`. The class provides a member function returns a reference to that image ,as well as functions to draw into it.